# Como varrer uma string e verificar conteúdo dentro dela?

Tags: c#, .net, string

Preciso fazer uma verificação com um determinado texto dentro de uma `string`.
Como faço para percorrer essa *string* e procurar o texto para fazer essa verificação ?

Exemplo:

```
If(dentro da string contém "Olá")
{
   Mostre o valor determinado para essa string;
}
```

Comment: Dê mais detalhes, coloque o que já fez, mostre onde está tendo dificuldade. O que é essa verificação? Eu acho que está pergunta já foi respondida algumas vezes aqui.

Comment: O que é "Mostre o valor determinado para essa string"?

Comment: Método String.Contains? https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Com o Contais() dá @FernandoMondo ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utilize o método [`Contains()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_String_Contains_System_String_) para saber se um texto está presente dentro de outro:

```
if ("Olá Mundo".Contains("Olá")) {
    //Faça o que quer aqui
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Contains.cs).

Answer (score 3):

O método **Contains()** retorna um valor que indica se uma subcadeia de caracteres especificada ocorre nesta cadeia de caracteres.

```
string suaString = "Olá mundo";

if (suaString.Contains("Olá") == true)
{
    Console.Write("A string contain 'Olá' ");
}
```

Como o método Contains() retorna um Boolean e foi utilizado dentro de um IF você não precisar ficar validando com `suaString.Contains("Olá") == true`, fiz dessa forma apenas para facilitar seu entendimento, então normalmente fazemos assim:

```
string suaString = "Olá mundo";

if (suaString.Contains("Olá"))
{
    Console.Write("A string contém 'Olá' ");
}
```

[Referência](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Consegui aqui @Renan valeus.

Comment: Usar um `== true` em `if` é ruim hein?

Comment: O método contains já nao retorna um booleano? Pra que fazer esse `== true` ai?

Comment: @bigown kkkkkkkk

Comment: Verdade, não é necessário. Facilita no exemplo para quem está começando. Vou editar a resposta :-)